# iOS: Objective-C creating class property error: Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to use class property following this [example](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/objective-c-class-properties/). But I'm getting the following error:"Use of undecleared identifier '_myProperty'".

Here is my implementation:

```
@interface myClass()

@property (class,strong,nonatomic) NSString *myProperty;

@end


+ (NSString*)myProperty
{
    if (!_myProperty) {

    }
    return [NSString new];
}
```

[image]

Why I'm getting this error? or any of you knows a work around this?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: I am not familiar with objective-c syntax but question seems like your variable myProperty is working like a computed variable a getter .  Which you have not declared anywhere in other words not provided any initial value. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class properties don't get synthesized in Objective-C.  You have to provide your own backing variable and your own getter/setter:

```
static NSString *_myProperty = nil;

+ (NSString *)myProperty {
    if (!_myProperty) {
        _myProperty = [NSString new];
    }

    return _myProperty;
}

+ (void)setMyProperty:(NSString *)myProperty {
    _myProperty = myProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class properties and never auto-synthesised, the getter and/or setter must be implemented, and no backing variable is automatically created for them.

If your property needs a variable you must declare one, use a `static` global in the implementation file - that is effectively a "class variable" in Objective-C. Alternatively if you only require a getter you can declare a `static` variable local to the getter itself, further reducing its visibility and keeping the getter and variable together as a package.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In fact, class property is not a member of a class. So it will be created at once and all instances will use this one. So there is nothing to synthesize.